# Pandas, large file with varying number columns, in memory append

Tags: database, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I would like to maintain a large PyTable in a hdf5 file.
Normally as new data comes I would append to the existing table:

```
    store = pd.HDFStore(path_to_dataset, 'a')
    store.append("data", newdata)
    store.close()
```

However, if the columns of old stored data and those of the incoming newdata are partially only overlapping, it is  returned the following error:

```
Exception: cannot match existing table structure for [col1,col2,col3] on appending data
```

In these cases, I would like to get a behavior similar to the normal DataFrame append function
which fills non overlapping entries with NAN

```
import pandas as pd
a = {"col1":range(10),"col2":range(10)}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
b = {"b1":range(10),"b2":range(10)}
b = pd.DataFrame(b)
a.append(b)
```

Is it possible have a similar operation "in memory", or do I need to create a completely new file?

Comment: HDFStore stores row-oriented, so this is currently not possible. You could need to read it, append, and write it out. Possibly you could use: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#multiple-table-queries

Comment: The best way to do this is to create the table with all columns that are possible at the beginning (and just leave them nan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HDFStore` stores row-oriented, so this is currently not possible.

You could need to read it in, append, and write it out. Possibly you could use: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#multiple-table-queries

However, you could also create the table with all columns that are possible at the beginning (and just leave them nan).